# ripping a dvd into an iso image using k9 but getting no sound

Tags: dvd, burning

I m trying to rip a dvd using k9 from ubuntu software center.I have saved it as an iso file.I have burned it three times and each time the video turns out great but I have no sound in vlc or a standalone video player.Anyone ran across this or know a fix for it?Maybe know a program that works?I have noticed k9 saying audio"unknown"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ripping typically means some kind of re-encoding the data to some other format while in your case it appears you simply want to dump the disc to an ISO image. Just in case the original dvd might have some kind of protection, I'd recommend using dvddecryper to create the iso. It is a windows app which works fine under wine and will typically be able to handle protected discs.

Comment: Please note that in some locations, this is illegal.